# How to delete columns in a panda dataframe with empty headers and no values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've found a way of deleting columns based on specific header titles and so on but can't figure out how to delete all the empty columns in a table at the same time.

I'm scraping a table that has 10 columns. Eight of those columns have headers and two that don't have headers don't have any values inside the columns either. I want to find an easy way to delete all columns that have an empty header and empty values inside. I cannot actually see the columns but when I look at the shape of the dataframe, you can see that it has two extra empty columns.

https://www.espncricinfo.com/series/8634/scorecard/1173069/australia-women-vs-south-africa-women-2nd-semi-final-icc-womens-t20-world-cup-2019-20

This is the page I'm trying to scrape using beautiful soup. Can't share the code at the moment as I don't have access to my work computer but if you look at the table with data-reactid="294" and the headers "BOWLING", "O", "M", etc. you can see in the code that is has two empty header texts. My panda dataframe looks identical to that table but it's shape is 5x10 because it has two empty unwanted columns in it. Hope that helps but if not, I can put the code in when I get back to work but essentially the data frame looks identical to the table, with an index column.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

def url_scraper(url):
    response=requests.get(url)
    html=response.text
    soup=BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
    return soup

def first_inns_bowling_scorecard_scraper(url):
    soup=url_scraper(url)
    for divs in soup.find_all("div",{"id":"gp-inning-00"}):
        for bowling_div in soup.find_all("div",{"class":"scorecard-section bowling"}):
            table_headers=bowling_div.find_all("th")
            table_rows=bowling_div.find_all("tr")[1:]
    headers=[]
    for th in table_headers:
        headers.append(th.text)

    data = []
    for tr in table_rows:
        td = tr.find_all('td')
        row = [tr.text for tr in td]
        data.append(row)
    df=pd.DataFrame(data, columns=headers)
    df.dropna(axis=1, how='all', inplace=True)
    return df.shape
```

Comment: Can you share an input example? It'll make it much easier to help.

Comment: Yep, I've added the code - sorry I couldn't add it in earlier - didn't have access at the time.

Answer (score 1):

If all cells of columns are with NaN contents, you can use:

```
df.dropna(axis=1, how='all', inplace=True)
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for what I'm trying (maybe because the contents aren't NAN?) I've edited the question to add in the code now.